# security consideration : spring-struts usage of struts 1.x

Tags: spring-security

spring-struts JAR is using struts version 1.x which is [deprecated](https://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html). Isn't this posing a security risk.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, every Spring version with spring-struts jar is end-of-life as well.

Comment: any recommendations on what should be used instead of spring-struts JAR like https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-struts/3.2.18.RELEASE

Comment: I recommend Thymeleaf.